# Подскажите как улучшить код?

Tags: pascal, инспекция-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
program lr3_p1;
    var x,y,yk,e : double;
    n,i : integer;
    begin
        writeln('Введите x[0.7;2.2]= '); read(x);
        writeln('Введите n= '); read(n);
        yk := x;
        y := exp((1/3) * ln(x));
        i := 1;
        while i <= n do
        begin
           yk := yk + 1/3 * (x/sqr(yk) - yk);
           e := abs(y - yk);
           writeln('y',i,'=',yk:5,'      e=',e:5);
           i := i + 1;
        end;
    end.
```

Comment: i:= i+1 можно заменить как inc(i);

Comment: Вставь задачу не картинкой, а текстом

Comment: И почему while а не обычный for тут?